# Maximum number of IntelliJ Run Configurations before they roll off

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, If I right-click on a class and choose Run 'XYZ', it adds them to the Run Configurations dialog.

This is fine, but after adding 6 new Run Configs this way, it rolls off the configs you've losed least recently.  This is annoying if I run 6 different junit tests individually, then suddenly run configs I want to keep are deleted.

Is there anyway to increase the limit from 6?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can open `Run` |  `Edit Configurations` and check `Share` checkbox for those configurations you want to save. And those will no be deleted.

Or, if you don't want it to be shared, you can click `Save` icon in the same configuration window. This configuration will also not be deleted.

You can find more information [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-saving-temporary-run-debug-configurations.html)

Comment: Yet still, is there a way to increase the limit?

Comment: @Danijel, yes, doc says : "By default, five temporary run configurations are allowed per project, so when you create the sixth configuration, the one created first is removed, and so on. To change this limit, use the Temporary configurations limit field in the Templates page of the Run/debug configurations dialog."

Comment: Latest (2022.2.2): Go to Preferences->Advanced Settings in the Run/Debug section set the "Temporary configurations limit"

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post but I got the same issue and managed to find out how to set the limit.

From IntelliJ documentation:

> > By default, 5 temporary configurations are allowed per project. You can change this limit via the Edit Configurations dialog.

Link to [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/run-debug-configurations.html#d723894e77) on how to change the limit.